# For which values of $x$is the angle between the vectors $45^{o}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I have the vectors:

$v = (1, 0, 1)$ and $w = (1, x, 2)$

How do I find out which values $x$ has to be to make the angle between $v$ and $w $ of 45° degrees?

What I have tried to do is:

$$v\cdot w = ||v||\cdot||w|| \cdot \cos(45°)$$

$$\frac{v\cdot w}{||v||\cdot||w||} = \cos(45°)$$

I calculated that $||v||\cdot||w|| = \sqrt{5+x^2}$

$$\frac{v\cdot w}{\sqrt{5+x^2}} = \cos(45°)$$

Which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you know the algebraic definition of the dot product? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition

Comment: And note that $||v||=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @pillikasnazsaxc  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$\langle v,w\rangle = ||v||\cdot||w|| \cdot \cos(45°)$$

that is

$$1\cdot 1+0\cdot x+1\cdot 2=\sqrt{5+x^2}\sqrt{2}/2$$

$$3\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{5+x^2}$$
$$18=5+x^2$$
$$x^2=13$$
thus

$$\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{x=\pm \sqrt{13}}
$$